# Print part of a string in C

Tags: c, c-strings

Is there a way to only print part of a string?

For example, if I have

```
char *str = "hello there";
```

Is there a way to just print `"hello"`, keeping in mind that the substring I want to print is variable length, not always 5 chars?

I know that I could use a `for` loop and `putchar` or that I could copy the array and then add a null-terminator but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way?

Comment: what's the character or criteria you want to stop on? it's hard to answer this question without clarification

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
int length = 5;
printf("%*.*s", length, length, "hello there");
```

Comment: @SiegeX: Yup - adding the `include <stdio.h>\nintmain(void)\n{` did you in... :-)

Comment: Of course, if he wants to print to stderr, or a file, or to a label in some GUI, classic `printf` won't help. Maybe make a note of sprintf/fprintf too?

Comment: @Chris Charagaruk: Quite true -- but given that he mentioned `putchar`, printing to `stdout` seemed reasonable.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Doesn't hurt to be generalist anyway.

Comment: @Chria Charabaruk: Quite true -- but I tend to presume that he also realizes that sprintf, fprintf, etc., all use the same formatting as printf...

Comment: `printf("%.*s", length, "hello there")` will do the trick as well -- the first * just means that a sub-`length` string will be padded to `length` characters, which may or may not be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 24):

This will work too:

```
fwrite(str, 1, len, stdout);
```

It will not have the overhead of parsing the format specifier. Obviously, to adjust the beginning of the substring, you can simply add the index to the pointer.

Comment: Although I *love* using `printf`-style formatting, this is the most simple hence most elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strncpy`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strncpy.html) to duplicate the part of your string you want to print, but you'd have to take care to add a null terminator, as `strncpy` won't do that if it doesn't encounter one in the source string. A better solution, as Jerry Coffin pointed out, is using the appropriate `*printf` function to write out or copy the substring you want.

While `strncpy` can be dangerous in the hands of someone not used to it, it can be quicker in terms of execution time compared to a `printf`/`sprintf`/`fprintf` style solution, since there is none of the overhead of dealing with the formatting strings. My suggestion is to avoid `strncpy` if you can, but it's good to know about just in case.

```
size_t len = 5;
char sub[6];
sub[5] = 0;
strncpy(sub, str + 5, len); // char[] to copy to, char[] to copy from(plus offset
                            // to first character desired), length you want to copy
```

Answer (score 0):

*printf* and friends work well when that's all you want to do with the partial string, but for a more general solution:

```
char *s2 = s + offset;
char c = s2[length]; // Temporarily save character...
s2[length] = '\0';   // ...that will be replaced by a NULL
f(s2);  // Now do whatever you want with the temporarily truncated string
s2[length] = c;      // Finally, restore the character that we had saved
```

Comment: This will give UB if you pass a string literal (which is what the OP shows...)

Comment: This is also not thread-safe.  But yes for thread-private buffers that you know are writeable, this is a decent idea.  Or better, modify your functions to provide an explicit-length interface instead of making them scan for a length you already know.