# Is it possible in printf to set number of chars

Tags: c, printf

Is it possible in `C` to set a number of chars to be output from string?

```
char const *str = "abcdefgh";
printf("%???s", str);
```

What should be placed instead of ??? to output `abc`?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841219/print-part-of-a-string-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is  , you can use `printf("%.3s" , str)` , or `printf("%.*s" , 3 , str);`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you could use a precision specifier, which would look something like this

```
printf("%.3s", str); // this prints "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` has the following definition:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

A format specifier follows this prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

You can take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to get an overview about these specifiers.

```
.number
```

> For s: this is the maximum number of characters to be printed. By
>   default all characters are printed until the ending null character is
>   encountered.

However, as written by Happy Yellow Face, `printf("%.3s", str);` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This question does say "**set** number of chars" and not "**limit** number of chars".

The 3 solutions presented do the second.  This is apparent when `str` is small like "ab".

To "set" the number to 3 use

```
printf(">%3.3s<\n" , "abcdef");
printf(">%3.3s<\n" , "ab");        // right justify
printf(">%-3.3s<\n" , "ab");       // left justify
printf(">%*.*s<\n" , 3, 3, "ab");  // right justify
printf(">%*.*s<\n" , -3, 3, "ab"); // left justify

>abc<
> ab<
>ab <
> ab<
>ab <
```

`>` `<` added for display purpose only.