# Is this possible with printf?

Tags: c, printf, libc

I understand that, with an oversize string, you can print out the first few characters with:

```
printf(".5s\n",string);
```

and with an undersize string, you can pad it with space:

```
printf("% 5s\n",string);
```

Is there a way to achieve both of these at once? i.e. pad it with 0 or space if it's short, and truncate it if it's long?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print part of a string in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841219/print-part-of-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can just combine it to this:

```
printf("%5.5s\n", string);
```

So if your string is 1, the output is:

```
    1
//^ 4 Spaces here
```

And if your string is 123456, the output is:

```
12345
   //^ 6 doesn't get displayed
```

Also for more information about `printf()` and as a reference see this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! Thanks.