# How can I fix the length of a string in printf when called from RISC-V assembly?

Tags: assembly, c-strings, libc, calling-convention, riscv

I want to get some output on a RISC-V program (assembly) running on top of pk on Spike using newlib.

I can call printf with null terminated strings eg (snippet)

```
la a0 msg_
jal printf

.data
msg_ .ascii "MESSAGE IS \n"
.equ len_msg_, . - msg_
```

Will print out MESSAGE IS - but how do I pass the length of the string to the call? I have tried a1 - a7 and it doesn't *seem* to be them and nor can I get putting the length I want on the stack to work (I might just be doing this wrong but in any case more or less the first thing the printf function seems to do is save lots of registers on the stack so I don't think that would work).

To add to my puzzlement, I have used Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/vscGPG) and I can see no sign that anything for the length is being passed. What have I missed?

Comment: `printf` doesn't use a string length passed as a parameter, it merely prints the characters of the string until it reaches a C-style nul character terminator.  So, if you want to use `printf` or `puts`, pass it a C-style nul-character terminated string.  `printf` needs the formatting string to be nul-character terminated; it also needs addition parameter strings (e.g. printed using `%s` from the format string) to be nul-character terminated.

Comment: Computing the static length of a string is syntax that is up to the particular assembler you're using.

Comment: I think you need to use `.asciz` instead of `.ascii` to make your string null terminated.  As Erik says, if you do that, then there is no need to deal with the length at all.

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4841240/2189500) (make sure you check out the comments there too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You null terminate msg

I'm not quite familiar with this assembly, but you want to get it to emit a zero byte. One of these might be correct:

```
msg_ .ascii "MESSAGE IS \n\0"

msg_ .asciz "MESSAGE IS \n"

msg_ .ascii "MESSAGE IS \n"
     .byte  0
```

In no case do you need `len_msg_`

Comment: The GNU assembler also accepts [`.string`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html#String), which also includes the zero byte.  That's what OP's Compiler Explorer output has.

Comment: @NateEldredge: *Unless otherwise specified for a particular machine, the assembler marks the end of each string with a 0 byte* - so apparently on some machines, it's `.ascii` instead of `.asciz`.  I'd suggest always using `.asciz` to make it explicit, and so readers don't have to try to remember exactly what the semantics are.  GAS has lots of aliases of directives for compat with various Unix assemblers, some being objectively better in terms of clarity than others.  Although `string16` / `string32` don't have `.ascii`/`asciz ` equivalents if you want UTF-16 / UTF-32.